# Downloading or Accessing a PDF webpage in Cucumber/Capybara

Tags: pdf, cucumber, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

I am currently testing a web app which generates and displays a PDF as a page.  This is done while you are in a session which has you logged in.

The system itself is written in python, but the test code is written in ruby using Cucumber supported by Capybara and Poltergeist (phantomjs).

There are several solutions for testing the content of a pdf, but accessing or downloading the pdf is the issue.

Using the visit command with capybara:

```
page.visit "http://web_app_url/stuff/pdf_name.pdf"
```

Or using a link:

```
page.click_link("PDF")
```

Results in a failure and will not move to that page.

Using this code to open up the page directly and save the pdf:

```
open('pdf_name.pdf', 'wb') do |file|
  file << open("http://web_app_url/stuff/pdf_name.pdf").read  
  file.write("register.pdf")
end
```

The issue with this is that it is run outside of the capybara session, and therefore redirects to the login screen - giving me a lovely pdf with the content of the login screen.

What I would like to do is use the above code but within the session that capybara is using.  However if that is not possible the next best thing would just be to download and save the file.

Any ideas would be awesome.  Thank you.